# Debugging Go API with Delve and Docker - Can't reach API with Postman

Tags: docker, go, goland, delve

I am trying to debug a Go API with Docker and Goland.

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2018/04/30/debugging-containerized-go-applications/) and I could make it work when I am debugging a Go App.

But my app is an API, so it starts, and I expect that when I make my request via Postman, my API should stop at a breakpoint.

What is happening is that the API is not responding, and is not invoked.

Here is the Goland App Log:

```
API server listening at: [::]:40000
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Creating an Engine instance with the Logger and Recovery middleware already attached.

[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
 - using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
 - using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

[GIN-debug] GET    /operations/:operation_id/keys --> main.displayKeysList (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] HEAD   /operations/:operation_id/keys --> main.main.func1 (4 handlers)
[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on :9999
```

It is telling me that my app is running on port 9999, but delve is running on port 40000.

I tried both ports 9999 and 40000 but none of them work for my request.

What am I missing?

Comment: ARe you running this inside of docker? Where are you accessing these ports from? (inside docker vs host machine?) How'd you invoke docker? did you set the port mappings?

Comment: Well, when I don't use debugger, I use it via docker-compose, and yes, I forward ports, so I can access it outside docker, but when using debugger, I can't access it anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application still runs and needs port 9999 to be opened and forwarded to make the requests to it.

Port 40000 is used by Delve and you should connect with the IDE to the remote service to allow it to start/continue using a `Go Remote` run configuration.

If you still have problems with this, either raise an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go and provide more details about this, screenshots or code to replicate would be great to have, or ping us on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/GoLandIDE)/[Gophers Slack](https://invite.slack.golangbridge.org/) in #goland channel.

Comment: I add a port forwarding error with debugger! Thanks for your reply, it helped me find the solution